# Is recompiling a long running query a good habit

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have some long running (a few hours) stored procedures which contain queries that goes to tables that contain millions of records in a distributed environment. These stored procedures take a date parameter and filters these tables according to that date parameter.

I've been thinking that because of the parameter sniffing feature of SQL Server, at the first time that my stored procedure gets called, the query execution plan will be cached according to that specific date and any future calls will use that exact plan. And I think that since creating an execution plan takes only a few seconds, why would I not use `RECOMPILE` option in my long running queries, right? Does it have any cons that I have missed?

Comment: If there are 1000 users to call that sp every minute, recompilations are not what you want. If you execute your sp once a day in DWH environment, recompilations are only beneficial

Comment: It's unlikely the recompile is harmful, but it may not do you much good either. If you neglect to maintain table statistics, for example (and that's easy to do with large tables, as the threshold for automatic updates only grows), you'll get the same crappy execution plan every time. Or conversely, the first plan may have been aces because the range you're querying *had* proper statistics, and then the `RECOMPILE` hits, has to scan a range for which there are no statistics, and your performance tanks. Nice job breaking it, hero.

Comment: @sepupic even if 1000 users would make a call, one user will wait 1 hour and another will wait 4 hours (maybe because of a few index not being used because of "bad" query execution plan that's being cached). It seems to me like a tradeoff between cpu usage and (possible) long waiting times..

Comment: are the names of your stored procedure starting with sp_ ? That could also affect performance https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25348/still-wrong-to-start-the-name-of-a-user-stored-procedure-with-sp

Comment: @GuidoG it could, but would you really notice 50 milliseconds? 1/20th of a second..

Comment: @JeroenMostert Good point. Statistics are updated regularly..

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, for an analytical workload 50ms overhead is negligible. It's a killer for a high-volume OLTP workload, though, Bottom line is one should avoid the `sp_` prefix for user procs per the Micorosoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql).

Comment: You're right @DanGuzman, didn't think about it at that scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the query should run within your acceptable performance limits and you suspect parameter sniffing is the cause,i suggest you add recompile hint to the query..

Also if the query is part of stored proc,instead of recompiling the entire proc,you can also do a statement level recompilation  like

```
create proc  procname
(
@a int
)
as
select * from table where a=@a
option(recompile)

--no recompile here
select * from table t1
join
t2 on t1.id=t2.id
end
```

Also to remind ,recompiling query will cost  you.But to quote from [Paul White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440595/paul-white)

> There is a price to pay for the plan compilation on every execution, but the improved plan quality often repays this cost many times over.

Query store in 2016 helps you in tracking this issues and also stores plans for the queries over time..you will be able to see which are performing worse..

if you are not on 2016,William Durkin have developed [open query store](http://www.williamdurkin.com/2017/06/introducing-open-query-store/) for versions (2008-2014) which works more or less the same and helps you in troubleshootng issues

**Further reading:**
[Parameter Sniffing, Embedding, and the RECOMPILE Options](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options)